# Android Emulator - connecting to a public API over the internet

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I have a React-Native app that uses a remote API to to authenticate and login to the app. This works flawlessly with the iOS emulator, however Android is a different story. The network request fails when trying to reach the API address and my app is unable to authenticate with the API. I see a lot of documentation about connecting the emulator to localhost however the API I'm using is over the web and NOT local to my machine. Is it possible to make public http requests to an API using android emulator.

The emulator is able to use the browser and browse the internet fine.

Comment: Debugging questions need to include the code which experiences the error, and useful information about how it fails, for example logcat output, or Exceptions or return values recovered with the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

This is not enough information but one thing to check is to see if you have this permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Then, maybe you can post some more detail about what are you trying to do? like code snippets and such